# Linq Includes Alternative

Tags: c#, linq

I am a loading a entity from the database like so

```
    var profileEntity = await Context.Profiles
                                     .Include(x => x.MedicalRecords)
                                     .Include(x => x.DrugHistory)
                                     .Include(x => x.EmploymentStatus)
                                     .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

All is working fine, I was just wondering if there is a better way to include its non generic type properties rather using the `Include method` because this particular entity has a lot of properties I need to include

Comment: You may not *have* to load everything. The child entities will be lazily loaded when accessed. `Include()` is required if you intend to process the entities after closing the context or if you really need to process *all* of them, eg to serialize them into JSON or XML.

Comment: Yeah I am serializing them into JSON, should've mentioned that.

Comment: Yeah Why don't you just select an anonymous type of what you need?  Or use a repository pattern to wrap you common logic you need.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't just keep adding `Include`s and still expect the query to perform decently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to automatically eagerly load those properties ([Mechanism for statically defining eager loading for navigation properties](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2766643-provide-mechanism-to-statically-define-eager-loadi)), but you can create a reusable extension method for this purpose:

```
public static IQueryable<Profile> IncludeAll(this IQueryable<Profile> query)
{
     return query.Include(x => x.MedicalRecords)
                 .Include(x => x.DrugHistory)
                 .Include(x => x.EmploymentStatus);
}
```

Which can be used in a following way:

```
var profileEntity = Context.Profiles.IncludeAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to consider turning off lazy loading for those particular navigation properties by making them not virtual. Example below from the MSDN page.

```
public class Blog 
{  
    public int BlogId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Url { get; set; }  
    public string Tags { get; set; }  

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }  
}
```

See the section titled **Turning off lazy loading for specific navigation properties** at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) for reference.