# Optimize ef-core query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

does anyone have any ideas how to improve or optimize this query in terms of performance?
An Include cannot be used due to missing Foreign Keys / Navigation Properties because this is a scaffolded model.

```
using (var session = new Typo3DBContext())
            {
                var countryList = session.TxNeustageodataDomainModelCountry
                            .Where(x => x.Deleted == 0)
                            .Join(session.TxNeustameinereiseDomainModelTripCountryMm,
                                    country => (uint)country.Uid,
                                    tripMM => tripMM.UidForeign,
                                    (country, tripMM) =>
                                        new
                                        {
                                            country = country,
                                            tripMM = tripMM
                                        })
                            .Join(session.TxNeustameinereiseDomainModelTrip,
                                    combinedEntry => combinedEntry.tripMM.UidLocal,
                                    trip => trip.Uid,
                                    (combinedEntry, trip) =>
                                        new
                                        {
                                            combinedEntry = combinedEntry,
                                            trip = trip
                                        })
                            .GroupBy(
                                temp =>
                                    new
                                    {
                                        Name = temp.combinedEntry.country.Name,
                                        Iso = temp.combinedEntry.country.Iso,
                                        Id = temp.combinedEntry.tripMM.UidForeign,
                                        Status = temp.trip.Status,
                                        Deleted = temp.trip.Deleted
                                    },
                                temp => temp.combinedEntry.tripMM
                            )
                            .Where(x => x.Key.Status == 2 && x.Key.Deleted == 0)
                            .Select(
                                group =>
                                    new CountryHelperClass
                                    {
                                        Count = group.Count(),
                                        Iso = group.Key.Iso,
                                        Name = group.Key.Name,
                                        Id = group.Key.Id

                                    })
                            .ToList();

                return countryList;
            }
```

Comment: You may use raw sql for fetching data from db. complex linq queries may lead to performance implication if not handled properly

Comment: @Tassadaque I wouldn't like to use raw sql, is there no suitable extension?

Comment: It's very likely that the best way to improve performance is by setting up indexes by profiling the resulting SQL query.

Comment: If your code works, this question might be a better fit for [codereview.se].  From https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: *If you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas... Performance... then you are in the right place*

Comment: Hey @dbc my source code works, but not in the desired time. I'm looking for a solution to get more power out of the query.

Comment: Using JOIN in Linq to Entities has really bad code smell.  Don't you have navigation properties?

Comment: A tiny thing you can do if you are not making any changes to the resultset is to add `.AsNoTracking()` to your tables.

Comment: You can also use "AsNoTracking()" - I see that you are not editing/saving the entities records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may analyze the generated SQL first and see if optimal sql is being generated. you may follow the [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/) link to start. Another good tool to work with linq queries is to use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). Some  of the common issue with Linq queries are

- The ‘N+1 Select’ problem (If you are using ef core 3 This and other sql related issue re being optimized):
- To greedy with row and columns
- Change Tracking related issues
- Missing indexes

Details of these issue can be found in above link an on internet also

Normally i go for stored procedure approach for complex queries as it saves lot of time of optimization of queries

Comment: Thanks, it was partly helpful. Are you aware of any Linq extensions?

Comment: i assume you are looking for include alternative you may see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566437/linq-includes-alternative

Comment: By Scaffold you mean you are using db first approach? then you should be relationship in db and you will navigation property

Comment: Then you have to go with join and it gives you better performance as you could join subquery issue if you are using old efcore version

Comment: By Scaffold means entity type classes and a DbContext class based on a database schema. that my definition